# ETH sent to an old DEXT address that has recently migrated

Tags: transactions

On August 17, I wished  to take part in DEXTools project and sent 24 ETH via Metamask. However, when I performed the transaction the old DEXT address appeared on Etherscan, and after having used due diligence to send these funds to DEXT it went to the old address.If I try to convert the ETH sent to the old DEXT address back to ETH using Metamask I only would receive a fraction of the original 24 ETH. Is there any way this situation can be corrected? Thank you for your cooperation. Have a wonderful day.
Sincerely,
G

Comment: Did you try contacting DEXT support? Can you provide more details? like DEXT address, source, transactions involved, etc. If the funds are locked in a contract to withdraw from it you can only use the provided functions.

Comment: Thank you Ismael, I have contacted DEXT support and am currently waiting their response and will update this post as more information becomes available.